# Determine If Plotted Lines Segments Have Open Profile

Tags: geometry

Given the four line segments where $s= $start point $e = $end point.

$- s(1,1)e(5,1)
 - s(5,1)e(5,5)
 - s(5,5)e(5,0)
 - s(5,0)e(1,0)$

The shape is drawn

[image: roughly like this]

Which clearly has an open profile.

Is there a method to go about determining if a group of lines contains an open profile?

Note

- The points are not always in order. (I just provide them this way for the sake of you guys.)
- The start and end points are subject to being flipped. (line direction is irrelevant as long as the points are the same)

---

I am a software developer, not so much a mathematician so any help provided would be great.

Comment: Well, the first point is not equal to the last point.

Comment: There should be some more tags, but honestly I'm not sure which ones.

Comment: Couldn't you try to match start and end points - if there is a start point with no corresponding end point then you must have an open contour. Unless you are allowing for closure by intersection. Then you could do some tests, maybe looping through all lines to search for nontrivial intersections. If point is found, then see if it lies on another line.

Comment: @JacobCheverie Two things. The points are not always ordered like they were above. also, no the lines are actually segments. (i edited the question)

Comment: Scan for intersections, $n$ segments must have at least $n$ intersections to be closed.

Comment: So essentially every point needs to have a matching other point for it to be a solid shape? @JacobCheverie

Comment: Not necessarily. Imagine two sides of an equilateral triangle. Instead of completing the triangle by joining the open endpoints, go from one endpoint to the midpoint of the other line. You will have a closed figure with a "tail". I am not sure if you are allowing for this.

Comment: @JacobCheverie Yea, but in the case of the triangle being made up of lines, there would be 6 total points instead of 3. I can write in the program that if there are only 3 points then to return true. (because there wouldnt be anything to compare the points to.) if there are 2 points then return false because thats just a line. and anything > 4 could have the function to compare the points.

Comment: That is why, in my answer, I would suggest creating a line from each segment and searching for intersection points (using equations of a line) within the actual limits of the segment. You'll need a divide by $0$ exception for parallel lines.

Answer (score 0):

You can use your collection of points to construct lines, one for each segment. Run a loop to find the intersection point of each line to each other. Obviously if the lines are parallel there will be none. When you find an intersection point, make sure that it is actually in the domain/range of both segments that it joins. If you have $n$ segments, you need at least $n$ intersections. This still allows for the possibility of having a "tail" but it will ensure at least one closed region. To avoid having a tail, you can do a slight perturbative check - when you have an intersection point, move out a small amount in each direction parallel to each intersecting line and see if the point falls on the segment and remains in the domain/range. Obviously one direction will (it'll be in the interior) but the other one shouldn't if you do not want tails.

**EDIT:** If you want to make it more robust, then you should adapt your algorithm as follows: If a line has $0$ intersection points that are within it's range, then do not include it in your segment count. The reason I say this is you can have many parallel lines and then a triangle. You will have many segments and only three intersections, implying you don't have $n$ for $n$. Ex:

### ---

### ---

### ---

### ---

### ---

### ---

$\Delta$

Would have 9 segments but only three intersections. Since the parallels do not intersect anything along their range, I would not count those toward the determination of closure (which you have with the triangle). Obviously you have a segment in space and do not have complete closure, but I do not fully understand your intent. Just coming up with possibilities.